# Safe to use file_get_contents with API Key?

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents, wireshark

Ok, so i have purchased an API key for a certain service, this service response in a `json` format, and my plan on getting this `json` response was to use `file_get_contents()` like so

```
$jsonResponse = file_get_contents("https://example.com/exampleapi.php?API_KEY=123456");
```

So my question is, is this safe and/or secure? Do i need to worry about users using something like `Wireshark` and getting my API key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cURL` and `file_get_contents` and other normal methods of HTTP requests should be sending the exactly same information to the server if they are configured in the same way.

What you may be concerned about:

- HTTP/HTTPS: `https://` isn't supported by `file_get_contents` in some distributions of PHP. Otherwise, if you use HTTPS, it is relatively more secure, regardless of what function you use to send the request.
- GET/POST: <s>I don't think `file_get_contents` supports POST requests.</s> However, since you are not a browser, the request method doesn't really affect you. If anyone is to intercept the connection, GET and POST won't do much difference. The only thing is that some servers store GET fields, but it's the server's responsibility anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info! When it let's me (says i need to wait 3 more minutes) i will mark this as an answer :)

Comment: `file_get_contents` supports POST just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is HTTP_S_ the URL is encrypted as a part of the communication, which is what makes this actually safe. Normal HTTP requests send the entire URL in clear text, which means it can be (and usually is) logged by third party proxies and the like.
That's where POST vs GET comes into the equation. (POST data isn't logged by proxies.)

As long as `file_get_contents ()` supports the HTTPS stream, then this is perfectly safe. If it doesn't you'll get an error message, which may expose your API key if not handled properly.
Always handle your errors, in other words! ;)